# .htaccess rewrite rules not working correctly

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up some simple rewrite rules but any url I enter goes to the first one every time.

```
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*/)?([0-9]+)?/$ categories.php?category_id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^categories/(.*/)?([0-9]+)?/(.*/)?([0-9]+)?/$ sub-categories.php?category_id=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^categories/(.*/)?([0-9]+)?/(.*/)?([0-9]+)?/(.*/)?([0-9]+)?/$ product.php?product_id=$4 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I basically want:

domain.co.uk/categories/category-name/1/ to go to categories.php
domain.co.uk/categories/category-name/sub-category-name/1/ to go to sub-categories.php
domain.co.uk/categories/category-name/sub-category-name/product-name/1/ to go to products.php

The 1 at the end of each url will be an ID for either category or product.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: These seem like they'd match all samples given, `categories/[^/]+/(\d)/$|categories/[^/]+/([a-z-]+)/(\d)/$|categories/[^/]+/[a-z-]+/([a-z-]+)/(\d)/$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the captured groups as optional in your rules. Have it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^categories/[\w-]+/(\d+)/?$ categories.php?category_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^categories/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/(\d+)/?$ sub-categories.php?category_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^categories/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/(\d+)/?$ product.php?product_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```